# Python Selenium Webdriver .click() Not Executing for Certain Elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, python-3.5

For the html source code found at the bottom

```
driver.find_element_by_id('cashAccount1').click()
```

works just find. But if I try

```
driver.find_element_by_id('cashAccount2').click()
```

the code moves on to the next line without successfully clicking the element. I know it is finding the element because I'm not getting an error and I did a simple 'if' statement to test it. Does anyone know what could be going on here? Thank you very much for your help.

```
<tr valign="bottom">
        <th id="cashAccount1" scope="row" headers="cashAccountNameNumber" class="firstCol text rowhead">...</th>
        <td id="cashAvailBal1" headers="cashAccount1 cashAvailableBalance" class="amount">...</td>
        <td id="RelatedActivities1" headers="cashAccount1 cashRelatedActivities" class="btlRelatedActivities">...</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
        <th id="cashAccount2" scope="row" headers="cashAccountNameNumber" class="firstCol text rowhead">...</th>
        <td id="cashAvailBal2" headers="cashAccount2 cashAvailableBalance" class="amount">...</td>
        <td id="RelatedActivities2" headers="cashAccount2 cashRelatedActivities" class="btlRelatedActivities">...</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
account = wait.until(expectedCondition.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cashAccount2")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", account)
```

where expectedCondition is imported as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expectedCondition
```

Hope it helps!